# Eclipse resets text encoding settings after every restart

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

For a project that has old legacy code that is encoded in Cp1252, i need eclipse to use this encoding instead of UTF-8 (which i normally use for all projects). If I compile that project while using UTF-8 as encoding in Eclipse, i get problems at runtime with special characters in the UI not being displayed correctly. Re-Encoding all source code files is not an acceptable fix at this moment and is not up to me to begin with.

So i went to Window -> Settings -> Workspace and changed the Text-Encoding setting to "Default: Cp1252". When i compiled after that, everything worked flawlessly. So far, so good.

However, after every restart of Eclipse, Eclipse changes the setting back to "Other: UTF-8". I've tried quite a lot of things to figure out why Eclipse does this and I'm coming up empty.

This even occurs with a completely fresh installation of Eclipse (i.e. just unzipped the file into an empty folder on my harddrive) and a newly created empty workspace. I literally started the fresh installation of Eclipse, created a new workspace and the setting for Text Encoding was "Other: UTF-8". I changed it to "Default: Cp1252", closed Eclipse, started it again and it was again set to "Other: UTF-8". I also tried setting it to "Other: Cp1252", but that doesn't change anything - it still resets to "Other: UTF-8".

I guess there has to be some system-wide setting being read from somewhere, but i don't know what to even look for.

Also, simply changing the encoding for the project to Cp1252 doesn't help, as i still get the issues with special characters - apparently i need to change the workspace-wide setting for it to work correctly.

I'm completely lost on this one. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 10):

For anyone having a similar issue, this is caused by oomph.
I fixed it in my environment by enabling the option "Skip automatic task execution at startup time" in the Ooomp -> Setup Tasks Preference Page.
I also unchecked the /instance/org.eclipse.core.resources/encoding entry in the "Preference Recorder" Page, but i believe that this is not necessary since i did not have this enabled.