# Every time I start/restart Eclipse it changes the Text File Encoding to Other: UTF-8 instead of the Default (Cp1252)

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, eclipse-neon, cp1252

so I have been reading and trying all the options I have found online with no success. The Problem: Every time I start/restart my Eclipse (Neon 4.6.2) the encoding is set back to **Other: UTF-8** (I want it to be the **Default Cp1252**).
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0RJ3.png).

I have set the encoding in `eclipse.ini` to `-Dfile.encoding=Cp1252`. Also tried the `-Dclient.encoding.override=Cp1252` option. 
No help. Also set all other possible encodings in eclipse->Window->Preferences to **Cp1252**. No success. Info: OS Windows 10, Java JDK1.8.0_112

Anyone have any ideas? I read that the encoding can be influenced by my JVM-encoding? I am really clueless here.

Comment: I'm also suffering on this problem. Perhaps one of the installed plugin is guilty?

Comment: It could be the Oomph plugin, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35342840/eclipse-resets-text-encoding-settings-after-every-restart

Comment: checking "Skip automatic task execution at startup time" worked for me. Tyvm

Comment: Why do you want Cp1252 anyway?

Comment: Because I have to work with some old project that use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by enabling the option "Skip automatic task execution at startup time" in the Ooomp -> Setup Tasks Preference Page.